# что VkNet - VkApi - проблема с заливанием картинки для MarketAlbum

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть простенький метод для заливания картинки под альбом Маркета в ВК:

```
private VkNet.Model.Attachments.Photo AttachPicToAlbum(string path)
{
    var uploadServer = VkApi.Photo.GetMarketAlbumUploadServer(_group.Id);

    var wc = new WebClient();
    var responseFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(uploadServer.UploadUrl, path));

    var response = VkApi.Photo.SaveMarketAlbumPhoto(_group.Id, responseFile);
    return response[0];
}
```

По факту response приходит пустым. 0 обьектов внути.

```
Url = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveMarketAlbumPhoto?group_id=129372114&photo=eyJwaG90byI6IjEiLCJid2FjdCI6Im1hcmtldF9hbGJ1bSIsInNlcnZlciI6NjM3NzE5LCJtaWQiOjE5NDk4NDA2LCJfc2lnIjoiYzI4MmNmNzdkN2E2MDJjOTYzZTE5NjdlMzQ3MzlkODgifQ&server=999&hash=a7d3c00bf6f76b058f917dde50f26f77&v=5.53&access_token=472a2bc9170f98b701fb019a6c3e971ef3a72c79a1c045743b4e4776b391cf105b6269a65fe5d8d4b13cf";
            const string json =
                @"{
                    'response': []
                  }";
```

Точно такой же код у меня есть для атача картинок в сообщения. Там все работает. А тут -- не пойму почему нет. =(
На всякий случай код атачча картинок

```
    private VkNet.Model.Attachments.Document AttachPicToMessage(string path)
    {
        var uploadServer = VkApi.Docs.GetUploadServer();

        var wc = new WebClient();
        var responseFile = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadFile(uploadServer.UploadUrl, path));

        return VkApi.Docs.Save(responseFile, "png")[0];
    }
```

Ошибок никаких не выдает.

Есть ли у кого идеи?

---

Как подсказал RoboNoob есть бага:
https://vk.com/bugs?act=show&id=4717174_65
Но если бы это было через нее, то фикс был бы следующим: (редактирование кода самой библиотеки):

```
    [ApiVersion("5.44")]
    public UploadServerInfo GetMarketAlbumUploadServer(long groupId)
    {
        var parameters = new VkParameters {
            { "group_id", groupId },
            { "https", 1 }// ДОБАВЛЕНА ДАННАЯ СТРОКА
        };

        return _vk.Call("photos.getMarketAlbumUploadServer", parameters);
    }
```

По факту фикс не сработал, проблема осталась как есть. Значит, делаю вывод что проблема в другом.

**Так же автор бага[и багфикса описаного] подтвердил что даная бага здесь не при чем.**

Answer (score 5):

В баг-трекере ВК есть информация о баге самого ВК по поводу заливания фоток на сервер по API https://vk.com/bugs?act=show&id=4717174_65

Comment: Судя по информации по линке все должно фиксится простым добавлением https=1 параметра в метод GetMarketAlbumUploadServer . Но по факту не фиксится. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: Кия прав. Проблема явно не в этом.